# How to limit Z rotation of object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am developing 2D game an I have an object to jump on. in rigidbody2D I freeze x and y but not z and I limit z in the script as :

```
private void FixedUpdate() { 
 Vector3 euler = transform.eulerAngles; 
 if (euler.z > 180) euler.z = euler.z - 360; 
 { 
   euler.z = Mathf.Clamp(euler.z, -35, 35); 
   transform.eulerAngles = euler; 
  } 
}
```

it can limit the z when player jumps on it but y and x are changing. it flies off screen do you know why would it move on x and y while they are selected freeze on the inspector.if I unfreeze y it works nice for z rotation but y falls down. Any ides ?

Comment: The code you show will not change the X or Y. There is obviously other code that is changing that. Could you show a [minimal reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: if I remove transform.eulerAngles = euler; then as it doesnt effect z it doesnt affet X,Y too. or if I uncheck freeze Y from the inspector then it doesnt fly off the screen but I need Y and X checked

Comment: I have checked and find out it is happining because of the polygon collider 2D. When I switch to the box collider 2D its all fine but I need polygon collider 2D any ideas ? @DerekC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was blind earlier.
The problem would seem to lie within your code's structure. Look at the `if` statement.

```
 if (euler.z > 180) euler.z = euler.z - 360; 
 { 
   euler.z = Mathf.Clamp(euler.z, -35, 35); 
   transform.eulerAngles = euler; 
 }
```

This is not doing what you may think. Let's rewrite with a different format but the same exact code :

```
 if (euler.z > 180)
   euler.z = euler.z - 360; 

 { 
   euler.z = Mathf.Clamp(euler.z, -35, 35); 
   transform.eulerAngles = euler; 
 }
```

What is actually be happening here is that because of the line after your if statement not being within the curly braces that code is being interpreted as :

```
 if (euler.z > 180) {
   euler.z = euler.z - 360;
 }
 euler.z = Mathf.Clamp(euler.z, -35, 35); 
 transform.eulerAngles = euler;
```

Technically, the last two lines are in a different scope but that isn't too important here.
Try to reformat your code with the intended structure and hopefully that should do it.